# Why HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERROR (3) when adding div to div on IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm using jQuery 1.5.2 trying to dynamically load a div from one source into a div in my container document. When I load the document on Firefox 4, the document loads with the message "Got it!", but when I load it on IE9, I get an HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERROR when it attempts to `.append()` the one div to another.

Here is the container:

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/harness-script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="main_cont">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the harness-script:

```
function load_stuff(widget_source) {
    var node = $(widget_source.documentElement).clone();
    // add the node to the main content
    $('#main_cont').append(node);
}

// Load and init the widget
$(document).ready(function() {
    resp = $.get(
        '/static/widget.xhtml',
        load_stuff
    );
});
```

The widget.xhtml is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div>
  Got it!
</div>
```

How can I re-write this such that it works cross-browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official answer from the jQuery team is that [loading XHTML into a DOM is not possible under IE](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8972#comment:13).

The only solution I have found is to do server-side browser detection and transmit the content as "text/html" instead of "application/xhtml+xml" when the browser is IE.

I imagine it's also possible to write a client-side handler that would append the node of not on IE, and explicitly construct a DOM from the XML if on IE, but that's not worth the trouble to me, since I have access to the server side.